# Shapefile for municipal communities in Armenia

Tags: shapefile, geojson, administrative-boundaries

Is anyone able to source a shapefile, GeoJSON or other file for municipal communities (ADM2) in Armenia?

They are described here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Municipalities_of_Armenia

Comment: Geospatial data questions are welcome here @PadmanabhaChowdhury

Comment: Have you looked in [DIVA-GIS](http://www.diva-gis.org/gdata)?

Comment: You can get Armenia administrative level 0-2 shapefiles [Here](https://data.humdata.org/dataset/cod-ab-arm).

Comment: @Pointdump - That shapefile is obsolete.

Comment: OK, how about 
[This One](https://data-download-gfw.hub.arcgis.com/datasets/gfw::%D5%B0%D5%B0-%D5%B0%D5%A1%D5%B4%D5%A1%D5%B5%D5%B6%D6%84%D5%A1%D5%B5%D5%AB%D5%B6-%D5%BD%D5%A1%D5%B0%D5%B4%D5%A1%D5%B6%D5%B6%D5%A5%D6%80-community-boundaries-of-armenia/explore?location=40.039152%2C45.046150%2C8.81)?

Comment: @Pointdump - that is the correct file. Thank you.

Comment: @Kohjah Breese , Pointdump hello, that link is dead. if anyone of you still has that file could you please send me or link me it? I'm really struggling as well, Armenia doesn't seem to have a national geoportal nor those borders are documented anywhere else. (comment by user "Julius Evola")